# Finding a square root of a permutation or explaining why it doesn't exist

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Let $\alpha,\beta\in S_6$ be given by:

$$\alpha = \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6\\3&5&1&2&6&4\end{pmatrix},\beta = \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6\\6&1&5&3&4&2\end{pmatrix}$$

(a)  Find $\alpha^{-1}$ and $\beta^{-1}$

(b)  Find permutations $\gamma,\delta\in S_6$ such that $\gamma\circ \alpha = \beta$ and $\alpha \circ \delta = \beta$

(c)  Find the least positive integer $m$ such that $\alpha^m = \iota$, where $\iota$ denotes the identity permutation of $X_6$.

(d)  Find a permutation $\pi\in S_6$ such that $\pi^2 = \beta$

(e)  Does there exist a permutation $\pi\in S_6$ such that $\pi^2 = \alpha$?  Either find $\pi$ or explain why such a permutation does not exist.

---

although I found a permutation (d)but it is not a good way to find a such permutation and  how to explain (e) it can't be found above my way

Comment: I assume that the only parts you are having difficulty with then are parts (d) and (e)?

Comment: I found (d) but it is not a good way.i want to know whether there is a proper way to solve  such a problems?